# Selenium IDE : How to press 'Enter' once text is entered in the search field using

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 + FireFox 52.0.1. I have a data table with search fields.

Once I enter text in the search field which command should I use to simulate a user pressing `Enter` (submit to search this text in the data table).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplish this with Selenium IDE

Command: sendKeys

Target:

Value: UTF for Enter - U+E007

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keypress` command to stimulate the button events.
Below is an example of searching `test` string in google.
You should specify the field's selector in the keypress event.
Here `\13` is the ASCII value of `Enter` Key.

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=lst-ib</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>keyPress</td>
<td>id=lst-ib</td>
<td>\13</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll mirror what's been said above, but, the best bet here is to use `SENDKEYS` and get the actual `ID` of the element from the DOM to pass in as the identifier (:value)